# HTML contact with ajax and PHP validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, contact-form

I am new to website development and recently I am trying to establish my very own website. I have a single page website where i am trying to incorporate a contact form without refreshing the page and provide a client side validation with PHP server side validation and finally to give a smooth success message when the form is complete.

The problem I am facing right now is the page redirects to contact.php  where a white page is shown and then no email is pushed. Please help me where i am making the mistake. Below are the codes which i am using for this website. Please help.

Index.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
    <div class="response"></div>       
        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php" autocomplete="off" name=postlink method="post">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" name="name" required />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" required />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-phone">
                <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10" value="" name="phone" required />
            </p>

            <p class="contact-lead">
                <input id="lead" type="text" placeholder="How did you hear about us" value="" name="lead" required />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Tell Us More About You" name="message" rows="10" cols="40" required ></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" class="submit" href=# onclick="submitPostLink()" value="Send Your Email"></p>
            </p>
        </form>         
    </div>
```

contact.php

```
<?php
$to = 'info@YYYY.com';
$subject = 'Website Request';
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Mobile Number:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>How did you Find Us:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['lead']) . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>More About:</strong> </td><td>" . $_POST['message'] . "</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

if($_POST)
{
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$lead = $_POST['lead']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
// Full Name
if (eregi('^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,20}$',$name))
{
$valid_name=$name;
}
else
{ 
$error_name='Please Enter a valid Name.'; 
}

// Email
if (eregi('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$', $email))
{
$valid_email=$email; 
}
else
{ 
$error_email='Please Enter your correct Email.'; 
}

// Phone Number Validation
if (eregi('/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/$',$phone))
{   
$valid_phone=$phone;
}
else
{ 
$error_phone='Please Enter your valid Mobile Number'; 
}

// Lead
if (eregi('^[A-Za-z0-9 ]{3,20}$',$lead))
{
$valid_lead=$lead;
}
else
{ 
$error_lead='Please Let us know how you found us'; 
}

// Gender
if ($message==0)
{
$error_message='Please let us know more'; 
}
else
{ 
$valid_message=$message;
}

if((strlen($valid_name)>0)&&(strlen($valid_email)>0)&&(strlen($valid_phone)>0)&&(strlen($valid_lead)>0) && $valid_message>0 )
{
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "Thank You $name for contacting us, we will revert back to you with your request within 12 hours!";
}
else{ }

}

?>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function()
{
$('#contact-form').validate(
{
rules:
{
"name":{
required:true,
maxlength:30
},
"email":{
required:true,
email:true,
maxlength:100
},
"phone":{
required:true,
maxlength:10
},
"lead":{
required:true,
},
"message":{
required:true
}},

messages:
{
"name":{
required:"This field is required"
},
"email":{
required:"This field is required",
email:"Please enter a valid email address"
},
"phone":{
required:"This field is required"
},
"lead":{
required:"This field is required"
},
"message":{
required:"This field is required"
}},

submitHandler: function(contact-form){
$(contact-form).ajaxSubmit({
target: '#response', 
success: function() { 
$('#span9').slideUp('fast'); 
} 
}); 
}

})
});
</script>
```

Stylesheet

```
#contact-form {
margin-bottom: 0;   
}

#contact-form p {
margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

#contact-form error {
font-weight: bold; 
font-size: 1.2em; 
color: #9d3131; 
}

#contact-form input,
#contact-form textarea {
 border: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
 border-radius: 0;

 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;

background: #26292E;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;
height: auto;
padding: 15px;
margin: 0;
outline-style:dotted;
outline-color:#09F;
resize: none;

}

#contact-form input {
width: 100%;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contact-form input:focus, #contact-form textarea:focus {
background: #26292E; 
box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa; 
}

#contact-form textarea {
width: 100%;
resize: vertical;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#contact-form .submit {
background: #26292E;
color: #7F8289;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 500;
padding: 16px 40px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: auto;
margin-top: 10px;

-webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear 0s, color 0.1s linear 0s;    
   -moz-transition: background 0.1s linear 0s, color 0.1s linear 0s;
     -o-transition: background 0.1s linear 0s, color 0.1s linear 0s;
        transition: background 0.1s linear 0s, color 0.1s linear 0s;
}

#contact-form .submit:hover {
background: #09F;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

#response {
margin-top: 10px;
color: #9d3131;
}
```

Comment: I cant seem to find your `submitPostLink()`

Comment: just return false from `submithandler :`, it wont redirect to `contact.php`

Comment: Dear @Baig, Please find the javascript code added for `submitPostLink()` which i have added in index.html   `<script language=javascript>
function submitPostLink()
{
document.postlink.submit();
}
</script>`

Comment: @dreamweiver can you please explain? Sorry I cant understand.

Comment: @New-Web-Dev: just add this return statement after `document.postlink.submit();` inside `submitPostLink()`, like this `function submitPostLink() { document.postlink.submit(); return false;} `. this will prevent your page from redirection

Comment: @dreamweiver thank you. lemme try incorporating that and test it.

Comment: Can someone please look into this issue and help me out.